# Post issue indicator gets clipped in small windows

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, design, post-issues

There has been a recent design change that places indicators of current and former post issues in the left margin of posts.  Unfortunately on my system I now see this:

[image: clipped object]

I cannot expand the window, and I am unwilling to make text smaller to fit the entire object on screen. Please provide a way to hide these objects, position them elsewhere, or simply remove them.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for an alternative position? And no, not the mod menu, that's where it was :P

Comment: Could just stuff it in the top of the right sidebar

Comment: @BenBrocka There are multiple posts on a page, it has to be attached to the post somehow

Comment: Status-by-design? Oh no. D:

Comment: It *still is* in the mod menu, @Manish - the marginal indicator just offers slightly faster access to a couple of things already available elsewhere. This has proved itself extremely useful for those of us on the Comm team, and the SO mods found it valuable as well; I can imagine that mods on smaller sites may not have as much need though.

Comment: @Shog9: Ah. Yep, it would be sort of useful on Physics, but not so much on Chem (where it isn't enabled anyway).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have committed a compromise change. If you have a wide window, it looks unchanged. If you have a narrower window, you get a small indicator in the margin that expands *inwards* to show the isssue details when you hover over it. If you have a *very* narrow window, you get nothing. This is in the next build.

Comment: Also, I've used media queries for this, so I can now claim "skilled in responsive web design" in my resume.

Comment: That sounds great.  Thank you.

Comment: @balpha The main culprit here is "deleted comment", which is too long. Why not simply show it as "comment"? Mods will know it refers to deleted comments... (or maybe give the box a "mod only" title, if you want to make it clear)

Comment: Apparently 1050px (full-screen on a portrait 1050x1680 monitor) is "very narrow", as I get nothing.  is that expected behavior?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, the cut-off is at 1070.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest simply displaying a minimal indicator instead of the full thing if the margin is too small. This would still show the moderator that there is *something* there, and it would not require any per-user settings.

Or it could just be hidden completely if the screen is not wide enough, it is a completely optional and pretty new feature after all. I don't think it should be repositioned, as it is not important enough to warrant using space in the main content area for it.

Comment: A minimal-width indicator icon would solve the problem in my case.  I think any moderator would quickly learn what the icon means without having the full text beside it.

Answer (score 4):

The margin indicator is intended to be a convenience feature - it provides an at-a-glance indication of information already accessible from each post's moderator menu. Placing it in the margin ensures that it doesn't interfere with anything else on the page, because *nothing important goes in the margin*.

Of course, if the browser window is narrow enough that margins aren't displayed, then there's no room for it. No matter; the mod menu retains this same information.

I suppose it could be hidden entirely when the margins don't allow room, but I would rather see it even partially clipped than risk missing it if I happen to use an insufficiently-wide window. This is a fairly utilitarian feature - retaining full utility even at the expense of appearance is important, else it might as well not exist at all.

Comment: There's got to be a better way.

Comment: Sure - we can disable it again. There was no intention to expand availability beyond the SO mods until folks saw screenshots with it and started asking for it.

Comment: PLEASE NO. I LOVE IT. I will pet it, and hug it, and love it, and call it charlie, and ...

Answer (score -4):

The existing design uses colored circles to indicate new notices of different types (replies, edits, badges, etc.):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I propose adding a similar indicator to the "mod" menu link to indicate additional content such as deleted comments

[image]

Comment: This is worse than both the marginal info and the display you get when you *click* the mod menu: it gives you a number without telling you what it means. If I'm checking up on a derailed comment thread, I want to know if there are deleted *comments* (and quick access to them); if I'm checking up on a deleted answer, I want to know that flags preceded that deletion. If I'm just scanning a page looking for anything untoward, a single number would be moderately useful - but even then it fails to give me one-click' access to anything.

Comment: Perhaps have two numbers of different known colors to indicate comments vs flags?

Comment: Yeah, Stack Exchange, especially the meta sites, needs more color.