# Can we make the post-issue indicator more tolerant of window size?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, moderator-tools, post-issues

There is a handy moderator tool that adds a little indicator to the left margin of a post that has deleted comments or flags.  This is really useful, as it pushes information to the mods instead of us having to know to go look for it.  Excellent efficiency improvement!

The indicator is designed for a window that is 1250px wide, and operates in a reduced capacity [down to 1070px](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167292/post-issue-indicator-gets-clipped-in-small-windows#comment581155_167310).  The monitor I'm using to ask this question is 1050px wide (it's  1050 x 1680 in portrait mode for easier document viewing).  I also access SE from a tablet that I believe is 1024px wide.

This means I can *never* see this helpful tool on either of those devices, even if I go full-screen with the browser.  It's not like I'm clinging desperately to ancient technology, refusing to give up my 13" CRT that went all the way up to, gosh, 800px wide -- I'm using reasonably modern, normal hardware here.  Portrait monitors may be a little unusual (though I know lots of people who use them), but tablets smaller than 1250px (or even 1070px) are common.

I've been previously told that SE site layout is designed for 1024px wide, and that seems reasonably common "out in the wild" based on casual observation.  Can we find a way to make some form of this indicator avaialble at that width?  Ideally it should be availble at even narrow sizes, but at least 1024px would be consistent with other site-design constraints.  Given that it goes down to 1070 now, may we please have 46 more pixels of flexibility?  Or move it from out in the margin to under the voting buttons so it makes use of whitespace that's already there?

This problem can't even be circumvented with a userscript right now; people who tried to write that to help me out failed because some needed IDs are missing in the HTML.  (I am not a script wizard and am repeating what I was told, but Tim Post was one of the ones who looked into this at the time.)  If you can't make it work to your satisfaction at a narrower size *but* we can get the hooks and a userscript, I'll be happy with that.

Comment: Kludge to get by: use your browser's zoom function to get yourself some more pixels rendered in less space.

Comment: But yes, this is an issue for me too. Not that my monitor is small, but it is partitioned with side by side windows and the loss of function on SE sites below 2/3 the width of my screen is frustrating when I know that stuff would fit just fine if the layout was more flexible.

Comment: @Caleb, agree on wanting it to work with smaller windoe sizes anyway; I almost never give anything the full screen, but even if I had to (temporarily) for SE, it still wouldn't help here as implemented (as you said).  As for zoom, I could do that but then my font sizes would change, so I'd have to adjust those, and then when I zoomed out I'd have to adjust them again, and... whee.  As a user with some vision problems I've already got a careful balance of text/zoom settings that more-or-less works, and I'm hesitant to disturb that.  But thanks for the suggestion; it may come to that.

Comment: I mentioned that *[window size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310939/282094)* was interfering with the display of the top bar (for me, and others with a newer mobile device) but you commented that you were unaffected. It's unfortunate that this has cropped up again elsewhere on the webpages. At least it's on Tyler's list; hopefully the entire problem will be resolved soon, and not one bit at a time.

Comment: @Rob oops, apparently I got distracted there or something and missed the "mobile" part.  I've deleted that comment.

Comment: That's OK. If you are affected a comment there, that the bug affects you also, might move it up the list a little. I ended up *here* searching for a dupe prior to posting a bug report - that meta.SE *sticks* in 'mobile view', though reloading the webpage can unstick it for the current page after which it reverts. It's annoying that a couple of months ago everything was fine, and the Devs understand what is causing these problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of today, no need for a userscript - our intrepid designer [Aaron](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/355163/aaron-shekey) whipped up this new design for the marginal indicators:

[image: icons shown below the vote tools: timeline, flags, deleted comments]

Ably implemented by [Brian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel), this improves over the previous design in a more subtle fashion as well: there's no additional request to load this information after the page has loaded, thus ensuring that it is instantly available and ready for use. And with the new responsive designs now available here and on Stack Overflow ([soon to be available network-wide!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes)) these indicators are readily accessible even on mobile devices, enabling you to quickly take stock of a situation that comes to your attention even when a desktop computer is not readily available.

Comment: Thank you Aaron and Brian!  I'm looking forward to having this mod tooling available on my phone too.

Comment: For anybody who needs the numbers to be a little bigger, this style override does the job (thanks vogel612!) (adjust size to suit): .js-post-issues > a { font-size: 12pt !important; padding: 7px !important;}

Answer (score 19):

I've written a userscript that (seems to, at least) fixes this issue, by moving the information from an extra widget on the side to just below the voting controls.

> [Source](https://gist.github.com/ArtOfCode-/3c8684f3df3f8d777af4) — [Install](https://gist.github.com/ArtOfCode-/3c8684f3df3f8d777af4/raw/552647e149b543b8aed7dd6c94059a3859f1ccde/move_mod_info.user.js) (Grease/Tampermonkey) — [Install](https://gist.github.com/ArtOfCode-/3c8684f3df3f8d777af4/raw/42327d879338500fcad0751719e86bcf0ff91c4d/move_mod_info.native.user.js) (native)

Mods will be familiar with the coloured icons we see for a number of things - it adds a pair of them under the voting controls, in the same order as the information is in the widget, and a third containing a link to the post timeline. (Hover over them for a reminder, if you're not sure.)

Comment: This is great!  I can now *finally* access that information in a browser that's "only" ~1000px wide.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the script, it's very useful — not just putting the information on the screen instead of outside the visible window but also with consistent colors. I do have a small bug report: [this post](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/65394) has [“1 deleted comment” in the margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQKWA.png), and actually has one comment, self-deleted. It has never had any flag. But with your script I see [1 deleted comment (correct) and 1 flag (not)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbZCP.png).

Comment: Thanks for the script that made the last 2.5 years of my moderating life so much easier!  Now that SE has built in a fix I've moved the checkmark, but it's not out of a lack of appreciation or anything.