# Allow moderators to more easily undelete comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, moderator-tools

Currently, to undelete comments under a post, moderators have to click a floating link that's off to the side, which makes deleted comments appear under the post along with "undelete" buttons next to them.  It's illustrated well in a screenshot taken from [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170489/236254):

[image]

The problem is that it's very difficult to get this floating link on the side to show up.  If you're on a mobile device or tablet, it's impossible to get it to show up, and even if you're on a desktop computer it won't show up if your screen width is too small.  Now there is a workaround for this, where you install a Greasemonkey userscript to adjust the position of the floating link so it will fit within the screen width.  But in my experience even that often doesn't work.

So I'd like to request an easier way for moderators to undelete comments without having to click the floating link.   I have two suggestions:

1. Add this functionality to the mod dashboard, an idea that was originally suggested in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170489/236254).
2. If making changes to the mod dashboard is something only done during major updates to the Stackexchange software, then at least create some kind of JavaScript command that does the same kind of thing that the floating link currently does, except without having to click on the floating link.

Would either of these suggestions be feasible?  By the way, note that I am not talking about the "show deleted comments" button that already appears on the mod dashboard; that takes you to a separate page and does not allow undeletion of comments.

Comment: Another idea for where to put an undelete link is at /admin/users/123456/post-comments?state=deleted

Comment: @animuson any update? This is annoying sometimes

Answer (score 11):

There is a very nice script [Stack Exchange Moderator Tools Improved](https://github.com/animuson/se-mod-tools-improved), which adds, amongst other goodies:

> - If there are deleted comments on the post, a "y deleted" option will appear to the right of the "x more comments" option, and will show all deleted comments upon clicking.

Clicking this link (which is directly under the question or answer) allows you to see and undelete the deleted comments.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have 2 sets of “revisions” and “timeline” links?

Comment: @JF Because I'm running multiple different scripts and they get added twice.

Answer (score 9):

This has been implemented. The undelete option now shows for moderators on deleted comments.

Comment: Is this part of overall improvement of moderator tools? If so, is there a list of bugs that are going to be fixed as well?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars It was not, this was resolved in 2018. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312558/1046749 The CM team is currently going through some of these older questions with status tags and updating them.

Comment: Good job. We should celebrate our wins.

Answer (score 5):

ArtOfCode wrote a [userscript](https://github.com/ArtOfCode-/Userscripts/blob/master/stackexchange/mod/move_mod_info.user.js) that I use on desktop computers that provides easy access to deleted comments on any screen size.  Once you have access, the "undelete" links are there.  I sometimes purge an entire thread and then undelete the few relevant comments using this tool, and it's great!

But it doesn't work on my tablet (or rather, GreaseMonkey/Tampermonkey doesn't) and it sounds like I'm not the only person for whom that's true.

If SE were to bake in this functionality, then we could all have it on all devices (when using the full-site view, anyway).  The back-end work is already done; this is purely a UI matter.  Isn't this better than that hard-to-see out-dented box that only appears when you're using a wide window?

[image: screen shot: controls under voting buttons]

From top to bottom, that's: number of flags,<sup>1</sup> number of deleted comments, timeline.  Everything fits conveniently within the space the site is already using -- no marginal protrusions needed.  If the post is super-short, it doesn't overlap with comments either because those don't extend past the post's left margin.

<sup>1</sup> I changed flag backgrounds from the usual orange back to yellow because I can't read the ones that use orange.  You'd get your flag color there, whatever it is.

Comment: Followup feature request: [Please make the moderator post widget more usable (small UI changes only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297446/162102)