# Some pages without the sidebar have become wider; moderation in a smaller window is now frustrating

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools

Recently the sidebar was widened a bit, but if your window isn't wide enough for the full width that just means you lose some sidebar -- the main content area didn't change.  That's good; we don't want to disrupt the usability of the primary content.

However, I've noticed that some moderation pages, pages which do not have the sidebar, have also become wider, and that *does* affect usability.  Here are some places I've noticed this (no screen shots because mod tools):

- on the moderator dashboard: the last column is now wholly out of view for me
- on the moderator users page: recent messages are cut off for me and require horizontal scrolling to read
- on the per-user comment history: posting dates are now out of view for me (those are important!)

I'm assuming that this got carried along with the [widening of the topbar and site banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273397/162102); I see that the "ask question" link is now out of view for me too and wasn't previously.

If I have to scroll to ask a question I'll live, but having to constantly scroll back and forth to do common moderator tasks is frustrating.  No, "make the browser window bigger" isn't an option.  It's not tiny; all this is stuff that used to provide a smoother user experience for me at this window size (around 1000px).

I don't *think* widening the moderator pages was an intended consequence of the design change, so I'm tagging this as a bug.  This doesn't happen on all pages; for example, the moderator analytics page is not over-wide.

Comment: I've noticed a lot of these too. Rather annoying.

Comment: Userscripting fixed my [last problem with mod tools that don't work in a narrower window](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188628/162102), but I don't know how to attack this one.  Also, I know I'm not the only mod with this problem, so I'm hoping SE is willing to lend a hand on this one.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as easy to do as it sounds :( (I know it because I'm currently trying to do it). That said, we'll move in the future from fixed value to percentages, which will allow you to display it at any sizes.

Comment: @Stéphane thanks for trying.  Moving from fixed values to percentages would be *great*!  Any idea of timeframe?  Is this "future" as in "we're actively planning this" or as in "someday"?

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's hard for me to answer here. I'd say "we really really want to do this" + "we'll do it after the big projects will be shipped"